# How can Visualize 3D points on C++

Tags: c++, opencv, point-cloud-library

I am developing a 3D reconstruction project using Opencv and PCL. In my code a voxel is represented by cv::Point3f coordinates

**Voxel.hpp**

```
    class Voxel
    {
    private:
//3D Coordinates of voxel
        cv::Point3f coordinates;
    public:
//constructor of voxel
        Voxel(float x, float y, float z);
        void drawVoxel();
    };
```

**Voxel.cpp**

```
//implement constructor
Voxel::Voxel(float x, float y,float z)
{
    coordinates.x=x;
    coordinates.y=y;
    coordinates.z=z;

}
//draw one voxel (3D point).
void Voxel::drawVoxel()
 {
        pcl::PointXYZ pt;
        pt.x=coordinates.x;
        pt.y=coordinates.y;
        pt.z=coordinates.z;
        pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer ("draw voxel");
        viewer.showCloud (pt);

    }
```

I get an error in the last line in drawVoxel() function. How can i fix that?

Comment: Try to describe line by line what you intend to do, and than you'll understand why it doesn't do what you intend. You create new cloud on each voxel and create/destroy viewer each time. Probably you should first add all voxels to a cloud, then display this cloud.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change like this:

don't create cloud and viewer inside draw-function. Pass cloud as argument:

```
void Voxel::drawVoxel( pcl::PointXYZ * pt )
{
    //pcl::PointXYZ pt;
    pt->x=coordinates.x;
    pt->y=coordinates.y;
    pt->z=coordinates.z; 
}
```

Once cloud is created with all voxels, draw it:

```
pcl::PointXYZ  pt;
Voxel v1(1,2,3);
v.drawVoxel(&pt);
pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer ("draw voxel");
viewer.showCloud (pt);
```

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, I have edited this answer and I wait for peer reviewed.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious,  I get the same error **no matching member function for call to 'showCloud'  viewer.showCloud (pt);** when using this answer

Comment: @Jeanne That means `CloudViewer ` does not have a member function named `showCloud`. Double check the documentation to make sure you're calling the correct function.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, No, CloudViewer has a function showCloud. I think the problem is in the parameter pt in showCloud()!